# BehaviorSubject não aceita valor inicial igual a null

Tags: angularjs, angular

Tenho o seguinte serviço, porém, ele não está aceitando que eu defina ele como null de inicio pro subject, fica retornando o erro: `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Comodo[]'.`

Este é o meu serviço:

```
  private comodoSubject$: BehaviorSubject<Comodo[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Comodo[]>(null);
  private loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getComodos(): Observable<Comodo[]>{
    if(!this.loaded){
      this.http.get<Comodo[]>(`${this.url}/comodos`)
      .pipe( tap((coms) => console.log(coms)))
      .subscribe(this.comodoSubject$);
      this.loaded = true;
    }
    return this.comodoSubject$.asObservable();
  }

  addComodos(d: Comodo): Observable<Comodo>{
    return this.http.post<Comodo>(`${this.url}/comodos`, d)
    .pipe(
      tap((com: Comodo) => this.comodoSubject$.getValue().push(com))
    )
  }
```

Minha interface está declarada da seguinte forma:

```
export interface Comodo {
    name : string;
    _id ?: string;
}
```

Não sei o que fazer para que ele permita que eu use o Comodo[] neste formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está falando que ele é do tipo Comodo[] então precisa passar um tipo válido que pode ser um array vazio.

```
private comodoSubject$: BehaviorSubject<Comodo[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Comodo[]>([]);
```

Comment: Era isso msm, obrigado!